# How to get same copyright & builddate info in all dll's across many .NET Core projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

We have a product consisting of ~100 projects, currently on .NET Framework. 
To get same build number, copyright and vendor information in all dll's, we have a common GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs referenced by all projects holding the attributes like AssemblyCopyRight, AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion. So we only need to update this single file to get correct information in the DLL's. Dll specific information is still held in AssemblyInfo.cs.

We want to port the product to .NET Core and want to be able to do same thing, but there these attributes are generated from items in the .csproj file, which leads to compile time error due to duplicate definitions.

Is there a way to disable this behavior in .NET Core projects or is there another way to get similar behavior as in .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With .NET Core, there is no AssemblyInfo.cs by default. But that does not stop you from adding one if you want to maintain your settings that way. You should turn-off the assembly attribute generation in the .csproj to avoid duplication.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This can also be done the other way round. Having the assembly info auto-generated. [This](https://www.fabiocozzolino.eu/autogenerate-assemblyinfo-in-.net-core/) blog post digs into how that can be achieved.